# Paypal SDK, how to get order details?

Tags: paypal, sdk

I am adding a PayPal button. Here is the code:

```
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',         
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":paypal_currency,"value":1}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            
            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>' + orderData.id + ' Thank you for your payment! ' + orderData.payer.email_address +'</h3>';            
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Here, after the payment is made, the text "Thank you for your payment!" appears before the text, I display orderData.id, and after the text I display the buyer's email orderData.payer.email_address.

I use sandbox and use card payment (card details taken from developer.paypal.com). Payments are made, the displayed orderData.id corresponds to the payment made. But the value of the buyer's email adress for some reason corresponds to the previous payment.

Those. I make the first payment - the correct email adress of the buyer is displayed. Then I make a second payment and use the same card details, changing only the buyer's email adress and name. In this case, after the payment is made, the email adress from the first payment is displayed on the page. Then I make the third payment - the email adress from the second payment is displayed on the page.

Why is this happening?

I wanted to display the payment details, but I see that the correct id is displayed for each payment, but the email address is displayed from the previous payment.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seems odd, but importantly `actions.order.create()` and `actions.order.capture()` are both deprecated and should not be used in any new integrations.

Instead, use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on a backend server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. The [integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) gives an example in Node.js , but you can of course adapt it and use any suitable language/environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are so many examples of the PayPal button - it is not clear which one to use. Since this is an outdated  code - I will study the link that you sent.